# Django annotations and filters

Tags: django, django-models

How can I query for count of related models satisfying a predicate? Let's say I have a model

```
class Comment(Model):
    text = CharField(max_length=100)
    parent = ForeignKey('Comment')
    created_at = DateTimeField()
```

and I want to select all comments with count of child comments created after certain date. Something equivalent to SQL

```
select c1.*, count(c2.*) from comments c1 
left join comments c2 on c1.id = c2.parent_id and c2.created_at > the_date
group by c1.*
```

Is there a way to do it using QuerySet?

Comment: Tip, use related name: `ForeignKey('Comment', related_name='children')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Comment.objects.filter(comment__created_at__gte=the_date).annotate(Count('comment'))
```

Comment: `filter()` must be placed before annotate.

Comment: @Skirmantas: not always true, but you are actually right in this case. See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses